# Recognize line of plants

Tags: arduino

I am trying to build an alternative to the standard line-following robot. I would like it to recognize a row of plants and follow it.

The challenge is to see a row of plants and recognize it as that. It is naturally not a solid line, but will be planted neatly in a row. It will be surrounded by weeds etc that do not grow in a neat line.

I would just like some pointers on how to approach this. Is this even feasible using Arduino?

Comment: You might be in a wrong stack exchange site.
Well just to answer your question, yes it is feasible, your robot will be doing some image-processing to recognize the plant since you mentioned that there will be weeds surrounding the plants.

Answer (score 0):

you might need CMOS camera, and maybe RGB readings from it, then apply computer vision algorithms to try to differ the plants from everything else. Too much complicated in my opinion. But yes check the Sensors from Digikey and see maybe you could you a laser or lidar to measure the distance from reference points and then implement PID on top of that, but then you need at least Arduino Due or higher. ATMEL SAM etc...